# Retrieve public key via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, key-pair

I tried to retrieve the public key content via aws cli following https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-key-pairs.html. But it didn't work.

```
aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --key-name mykey --include-public-key

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --include-public-key
```

Comment: You may want to update your AWS CLI. The latest version is `aws-cli/2.7.6` with which this argument works.  Previously I had a version of `2.2.x` for which I had the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works with the latest aws cli version.